# How to assign sorted data to immutable object

Tags: javascript, angular, immutability, ecmascript-2016

I am getting data from `ngrx/store` this data is sorted in front end. when the data sorted, i am assigning back to value, but no update happening. I understood that the data is `immutable`. But how to assign the value back to `immutable`?

here is my try: `this.data` - not updated after sort.

```
this.data = this.data.slice().sort((a, b) => {
  if (this.sort) {
    if (isNaN(a)) {
      if (a[sortBy] < b[sortBy]) {
        return -1;
      }
    }
    if (!isNaN(a)) {
      return a[sortBy] - b[sortBy];
    }
  }
  if (!this.sort) {
    if (isNaN(a)) {
      if (b[sortBy] < a[sortBy]) {
        return -1;
      }
    }
    if (!isNaN(a)) {
      return b[sortBy] - a[sortBy];
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: To confirm, `this.data` is an Immutable type? Is it `List`?

Comment: I would suggest you to use a pipe to sort the records.. Google it you will find plenty..

Comment: @JonE - yes you are correct

Comment: @Manish - the sort is parameter here. I am using for multiple component as reusable

Comment: @3gwebtrain even if sortyBy is a parameter you can use a pipe..

Comment: I don't see what the problem is here. `.slice()` returns a new `Immutable` value, and the `sort` will do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such scenarios you can use a `sortBy` `Pipe`. Below is a code that will help you out. The below code is capable of handling arrays of `numbers, string, objects` You can pass a key on which the sort needs to be applied. Also you can sort in reverse order if required.

Also this way you need not to modify your data and reassign. The pipe and angular will take care of sorting based on the inputs passed and same will be displayed on the UI. And you can use this Pipe across your code.

```
import {
  Pipe,
  PipeTransform
} from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "sortBy"
})
export class ArraySortByPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform(array: any[], reverse: boolean = false, prop ? : string) {
    if (!Array.isArray(array)) {
      return array;
    }
    if (array.length) {
      let sortedArray: any[];
      if (typeof array[0] === "string") {
        sortedArray = array.sort();
      }
      if (typeof array[0] === "number") {
        sortedArray = array.sort((a, b) => a - b);
      }
      if (typeof array[0] === "object" && prop) {
        sortedArray = array.sort((a, b) => a[prop].toString().localeCompare(b[prop].toString()));
      }
      return !reverse ? sortedArray : sortedArray.reverse();
    }
    return array;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps :). Let me know if you still face any issues.

Comment: How we can use it in ngrx?

Comment: @profiler haven't tried with ngRx. Let me know if you face issues.. I will figure out how to do that